# see trend change by group (python pandas dataframe)

Tags: python, loops, pandas, categories

I am trying to create a new dataframe based on the existing dataframe below. I am aiming to calculate the average change in clicks and categorize the campaigns accordingly.

Existing dataframe df:

```
campaign    |     date     |    clicks 
   A           2015-10-11       255
   A           2015-10-12       367
   A           2015-10-13       489
   B           2015-10-11       500
   B           2015-10-15       122
   C           2015-10-11       33
```

Goal dataframe df_categorized:

```
campaign | avg_change |   category
   A        0.3858       increasing
   B        -0.756       decreasing
   C           0         no change
```

I tried this code, but I get an error message TypeError: 'long' object does not support item assignment

```
 #standard packages
 import pandas as pd
 import numpy as np

 #upload data into df
 df = pd.read_csv('C:\Users\xxx\Documents\\ad_table.csv')

 df.head()
 campaign    |     date     |    clicks 
   A           2015-10-11       255
   A           2015-10-12       367
   A           2015-10-13       489
   B           2015-10-11       500
   B           2015-10-15       122
   C           2015-10-11       33

 #create empty dataframe
 columns = ['group','avg_change', 'category']     
 df_categorized = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)

 df_categorized['avg change'] = df.clicks.apply(lambda df:       df.pct_change().abs().mean())

 #create column
 df_categorized['category'] = 0
 # going up
 df_categorized['category'][df_categorized['avg change'] > 0] = "increasing"
 # going down
 df_categorized['category'][df_categorized['avg change'] < 0] = "decreasing"
 #no change
 df_categorized['category'][df_categorized['avg change'] = 0] = "no change"
```

Comment: Even though you call it `df`, the argument in the lambda function is an element of the series, i.e. a scalar. When you apply a function to a series (here `df.clicks`), the function is applied element-wise.

Comment: You can track average change with a simple last minus first

Comment: Also taking `abs` of changes will not tell you who's decreasing or increasing!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html#pandas.DataFrame.groupby) on 'campaign' and then [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html#pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply) a `lambda` that calcs the [`pct_change`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.pct_change.html#pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.pct_change) and return the [`mean`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mean.html). Then you can `reset_index` on this and add you additional category column using [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
In [239]:
gp = df.groupby('campaign')['clicks'].apply(lambda x: x.pct_change().mean()).reset_index(name='avg_change').fillna(0)
gp['category'] = np.where(gp['avg_change'] < 0, 'decreasing', np.where(gp['avg_change'] > 0, 'increasing', 'no change'))
gp

Out[239]:
  campaign  avg_change    category
0        A     0.38582  increasing
1        B    -0.75600  decreasing
2        C     0.00000   no change
```

this:

```
df_categorized['avg change'] = df.clicks.apply(lambda df: df.pct_change().abs().mean())
```

won't work, you're calling `apply` on a column so the lambda will be each row element which in this case is an `int` hence you get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'pct_change'
```

Even without this it doesn't give you the pct_change per campaign anyway.

Also don't chain calls on your df like this:

```
df_categorized['category'][df_categorized['avg change'] > 0] = "increasing"
```

it should be:

```
df_categorized.loc[df_categorized['avg change'] > 0, 'category'] = "increasing"
```

See the [`docs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy)

Comment: thank you! this was very helpful, especially the recommendations, I will use them going forward - when I run the code above on my whole data set, i get only positive changes or "inf" - what does "inf" mean?

Comment: It means infinite number, It means you're dividing by zero somewhere probably

Comment: I see; so I need to drop those values with dropna or df = df[df.clicks != 0]?

Comment: That sounds reasonable, in your scenario it maybe is meaningless to include them